# How how monitor events in AWS firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, alert, parquet, monitor, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am working on an infra where we receive an event from upstream and send it to kinesis firehose where we convert the json event to parquet and then send to our S3 bucket. In between eventbus and firehose I have SQS and lambda which transmits in batches to firehose.
Note : A single parquet can have multiple events inside that.

I wanted to know a good way so that I can monitor the json event coming across and the one converted to parquet in a day.